# Customizing the wordpress loop in twenty ten theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to customize the loop in wordpress's twenty ten theme to display one one post of three categories on the home page.  Is it suggested to use twenty ten?  I'm attempting to recreate something similar to Good Magazine's layout.

thank you

Comment: Hi Jason, I was only working off the the standard loop, which is a bit hairy in the twenty ten theme, I ultimately decided to build it from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $args = array(
        'category__in' => array(1,2,3),
        'showposts' => 1,
    'order'    => 'DESC'
    );

    query_posts( $args );
```

If you post what you have so far, we can give you more detailed answers.

Comment: Thank you cwhelms.  This is a great solution!

Comment: @MLS1984 Glad it helped. Please mark it as the solution if it is what you wanted so others can benefit from it as well!